# Synchronise a function with an API Call in React

Tags: reactjs, flux

Here are the steps going on in my app.

1. Update the state based on UI event.
2. Once the state updates make an API Request.
3. Based on the response of that API Request, make another function call that accepts two parameters, one object from the state that was updated in Step 1 and another from the response of API Request in Step 2.

What I am not able to do is how do I make my 2nd function wait for the first request to complete?

Code to update the state and make the API Request.

```
this.setState({
  // Set State here.
}, () => {
  this.props.Make_API_Call(params);
});
```

The two params I need to call my third function will already be in the local State of my Component after executing the above code. The problem that remains is How do I attach my third function?

Comment: You can return a promise from Make_API_Call function and while resolving that promise you can execute 3rd function. And returning a promise should not be hard if you are using some fetch library (eg whatwg-fetch) as they support promises.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your function `MAKE_API_CALL()` returns a promise. Once that promise resolves, the `.then` function (fulfilled or rejected) will execute.

```
this.setState({
  // Set State here.
}, () => {
  this.props.Make_API_Call(params).then(function(res) {
    thirdFunction(this.state.someValue, res)
  }, function(reason) {
    // rejection
  });
});
```